# More AtTask API POST Issues

Tags: api, attask

I'm working on a project to pull information from a SharePoint calendar and and post it into the atTask Time Off calendar.  This should be pretty simple, but nothing in the AtTask API works the way I would expect.  I've already asked about the "POST" action deleting existing records. Now I'm running into some strange rights issues.

I have administrator rights in our AtTask sandbox.  I am able to access the Time Off records (RESVY) for all users on the system.  I am able to delete them without issue.  However, I am only able to create new records (POST) for myself.  When attempting to create a new record for another user, I'm plugging in the sessionID from my login as the administrator and the other users userID.

The result is an error message: "You do not have sufficient access to edit this User".

It seems odd that the API would allow me to delete the RESVT records for another user, but no create new records.

We are using Active Directory for authentication into AtTask, so I don't have access to the passwords of the other users.  This is really getting to be a headache.

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

To update another users Time-Off the following 3 scenarios will allow you to mark time-off for another user. This is using the new access module.

1. You are a system admin
2. You have User Admin setting enabled in your access level settings (Located under the Fine Tuning option through the Edit Rights at the user level)
3. You have users who report to you (you are a manager) you will be able to edit users Time-off for users who report to you.